Using OffscreenCanvas to resize image inside webworker not working for webkit on playwright
I want some clientside image compression using a webworker. My code is already working on my local machine (FF, Chrome, Safari).
Its e2e-tested with playwright 1.44.0. Running the tests locally succeeds but running the tests inside github actions the webkit part fails.
I think its because of webkit  only partial supports createImageBitmap. However, the referenced bug report does not really help me at all.
Can you tell me how i can change my code to work on safari aswell or make my pipeline happy?

// worker.ts
onmessage = async (msg: MessageEvent<File>) => {
  const img: File = msg.data
  
  const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(img) // this is not working on playwright safari

  const offscreenCanvas = new OffscreenCanvas(imageBitmap.width / 2, imageBitmap.height / 2)
  const ctx = offscreenCanvas.getContext('2d')
  if (ctx == null) return

  // Draw the ImageBitmap onto the OffscreenCanvas, resizing it
  ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0, offscreenCanvas.width, offscreenCanvas.height)
  const blob = await offscreenCanvas.convertToBlob()
  const resizedImg = new File([blob], img.name, { type: img.type })

  postMessage(resizedImg)
}

//compress.ts
async function compressImages(images: FileList): Promise<File[]> {
  const files: File[] = []
  if (window.Worker) {
    const myWorker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.ts', import.meta.url))

    for (const image of images) {
      myWorker.postMessage(image)
      console.log('Message posted to worker')

      await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        myWorker.onmessage = (e: MessageEvent<File>) => {
          console.log('Message received from worker', e.data)
          files.push(e.data)
          resolve()
        }
      })
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Your browser doesn't support web workers.")
  }

  return files
}

export { compressImages }


Seems to work just fine for me (Safari 17.4.1 (19618.1.15.11.14)) Do you have an error message or something? The bug report is super old and all the related bugs have actually been fixed.

Ah excuse me, I've forgot to add that this code is not working inside my playwright testpipeline. On my own safari its working. I think I need to change the error description a little bit.

Well the error states that it's OffscreenCanvas that's not even defined there. Short of upgrading the WebKit version I fear you're out of luck.

Hm I tried to reproduce it with a minimal example, however Its working there... https://github.com/Theiaz/playwright-bug-webkit
Any ideas?
